# Xcode debugger is slow when setting "conditional" break points?

Tags: xcode, debugging, gdb

I use Xcode 5 to program with C. I lately noticed that the debugger in Xcode was very slow when setting a "conditional" break points.  If I remove any condition, debugger runs in normal speed.  I wonder if there is something I should have set in Xcode configuration.  Does anybody have any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if the breakpoint doesn't cause a stop, the debugger still needs to take control of the process every time to evaluate the condition.

If you need skip a conditional branch many times, it is often better to add the condition to your source, set the breakpoint on the new source, rebuild and rerun.

Answer (score 1):

I have observed very slow debugging when 'Queue Debugging' is enabled in XCode.